# Use the LMS algorithm to train a single perceptron neural network by finding the weights for a given data

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, algorithms, optimization

Basically, I have data set contain inputs and outputs for unknown system, I want to use the LMS (Least Mean Square), to train a single perceptron (neuron) NN, and find the weights $ w_1, w_2, ... $, for the given output.

Comment: All the NN libraries will do this if you choose RMSE as the objective (and many will do that automatically for linear output neurons). No effort is required other than setting parameters for the network, and you have already said you want just one output neuron. So just create a NN with one layer, with one linear neuron in it, and train it on the data. If this is something that you don't understand or know how to do, then could you please explain a bit more about where or how you are stuck? Otherwise it is not clear how to answer your question

Comment: Okay, I'm coming, I've a $200 \times 4$ inputs, and an output vector of $200 \times 1$, I want to **find the weights, $ w_1, w_2, ...$** I'm using Matlab m file for that with for loop and stuff, **also, not sure how to get the proper learning ratem $ \gamma $** , any suggestions ?

Comment: Learning rate you just need to guess (this is an annoying problem with many ML algorithms). Other than that, this seems like homework or coursework from a basic ML class. If you post **where you are stuck exactly**, explain what *your* problem with understanding is, then maybe the site here can help. Otherwise, you will get much better help from your class - just explain there what it is that you do not understand. Or just watch your lectures again, because it will be explained very well there